# Older driver, newer CUDA Toolkit leads to container startup failure - any configuration workarounds?

Tags: docker, cuda, gpu, driver, nvidia

NVIDIA starting from CUDA 11.x should in theory guarantee compatibility of their CUDA Toolkit libraries (typically shipped inside docker containers) and the driver library `libcuda.so` (installed on the host). This should be true at least when we stay within all minor versions of CUDA (11.0 to 11.8).

It should be therefore possible to run containers with newer
versions of CUDA on hosts with pre-installed GPU drivers built
for older CUDA versions. This does not work in practice though - CUDA-enabled containers (including the official `nvidia/cuda`) fail to run in such scenarios.

Are there any configuration workarounds that would at least enable containers to start (to test if apps have GPU access), if upgrading the driver libraries on the host is not feasible and downgrading the containerized CUDA Toolkit is time consuming and would potentially lower functionality?

Answer (score 2):

`NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA` is the env var in the image which contains the version requirements string for containers to start (the one which `NVIDIA_DISABLE_REQUIRE` ignores).

e.g. for `nvidia/cuda:11.6.0-base-rockylinux8`

```
ENV NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA "cuda>=11.6 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451 brand=tesla,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=unknown,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=nvidia,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=nvidiartx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=geforce,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=geforcertx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=quadro,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=quadrortx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=titan,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=titanrtx,driver>=470,driver<471"
```

https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/blob/master/dist/11.6.0/rockylinux8/base/Dockerfile#L6

There are two possible ways to be compatible in that string:

1. If the driver on the host machine supports cuda>=11.6 then we are compatible. So if we have driver 510.x that comes with 11.6, if we have driver 515.x that comes with 11.7, so we can use 11.6 due to minor version compatibility.
2. The rest of the string is describing forward compatibility, which is enabled by default in nvidia's cuda containers. The compatibility table for that is here https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#use-the-right-compat-package

So the issue we were seeing, which is similar to yours was trying to use nvidia/cuda:11.5.0-base-rockylinux8 on AWS A10G with driver 470.x. That requires forward compatibility, but the `NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA` only includes tesla cards (A10G appears as 'brand=unknown') in that image (it has been fixed in 11.6 and many other versions to include the other brands).

Also worth noting that the `NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA` picks out specific driver versions (the long term support ones) that they support 470, 510, 515, 525 etc. The images do not support the short lived branches.

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds such as `NVIDIA_DISABLE_REQUIRE` as recommended by an NVIDIA employee on Github [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1409#issuecomment-778089784) will ultimately fail (as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75030836/9962007)) to deliver GPU access for your apps. You need to synchronize CUDA versions between the driver libraries (on the host) and CUDA Toolkit (in the container), by either of two things:

- upgrade the host driver libraries (preferred),
- downgrade the container CUDA Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

According to NVIDIA [docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/user-guide.html#nvidia-disable-require) setting this env. variable to `true` (or 1) should disable CUDA version check at startup, and should work within the same major CUDA version (thanks to [minor version compatibility](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#minor-version-compatibility)):

```
NVIDIA_DISABLE_REQUIRE=1
```

I must warn you however, that this workaround works only superficially, letting your container with mismatched (newer) CUDA Toolkit start (no longer crashing on failing CUDA version check). In my case the workaround helped start the container with 11.8 CUDA Toolkit on a machine with CUDA 11.2 driver libraries. But the workaround will ultimately fail as soon when you try to test some ML algos in the GPU, they will fail to train in the model, printing error messages with various levels of specificity (with LightGBM even apparently "working", but at... 0% GPU utilization, i.e. silently failing). The most specific error message was given by Catboost:

```
CatBoostError: catboost/cuda/cuda_lib/cuda_base.h:281: CUDA error 803: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
```

while XGBoost errored with a rather misleading message:

```
XGBoostError: [17:49:24] ../src/gbm/gbtree.cc:554: Check failed: common::AllVisibleGPUs() >= 1 (0 vs. 1) : No visible GPU is found for XGBoost.
```

(Both of the above algos start working correctly in the GPU after CUDA Toolkit in the container is downgraded to match CUDA version from the host).